# Modify running GAE flex node app

Tags: docker, node.js, google-app-engine

We wanted to make a quick change to a running GAE application to enable logging of queries to trace a bug.

SSH'ing into a running instance it can be hard to find where the app code is stored due to the use of docker.

While [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) allow you to start a shell in the container instance, `vim` or similar isn't available in the container, so it's not possible to modify the code.

Below is how we figured out where to find the app.

Answer (score 1):

In GAE console, go to the side menu and choose `App Engine -> Instances`

If you're not trying to connect to your default app, change the drop down on the top left.

Then click on the SSH button.

Docker images are stored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` but there's a *lot* of them.

To find the one that contains your app, choose a file name that is unique to your project, for example we chose `messageProcessor.js` then search all the images for it.

(The SSH user doesn't have permission, so you'll need to sudo to run find on that folder)

```
sudo find /var/lib/docker/overlay2 -name messageProcessor.js
```

Hopefully you get just one result, something like this:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/14b22c856283a3231a55c79f54d298acb9750fc886037533ef830acf55a10116/merged/app/jobs/messageProcessor.js
```

Now you know where to find your app, you can edit a file:

```
sudo vi /var/lib/docker/overlay2/14b22c856283a3231a55c79f54d298acb9750fc886037533ef830acf55a10116/merged/app/some/file/in/my/app.js
```

Then restart your app for the change to take effect

```
# ps -ef | grep node
root     11152 11151  0 Sep13 ?        00:00:00 node /app/index.js
# sudo kill <the pid of your process>
```